# How to have Checkbox as ColumnHeader of dataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm developing a window application in C# VS2005. I have a dataGridView in which the first column has Checkboxes. Now i want the Column header also to be a CheckBox which if i select all the Checkboxex in the column should get selected.
How  can i do this.? 
I referred the [Code Project link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridView_winforms.aspx)

But if i use that, if i click the **FirstCell (not the Header)** all the below cells are getting selected. But i want a CheckBox in the Column header. How can i do this.?

Comment: Please provide us the complete code, as the code you have given is incomplete and got bugs. I need this code. Regards
Zuhaib

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I also needed to have a `CheckBox` in the column header of a `DataGridView` column.  Here's how I did it:

- Create a class which inherits from `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`
- Internally use a `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox` to store the checked state and provide the OS styled visual `CheckBox` representation.
- Use a `Bitmap` as a buffer and draw the regular `CheckBox` on it (using `CheckBox.DrawToBitmap`)
- Override `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.Paint` and, if necessary, update the buffer before drawing the buffer to the `Graphics` supplied by `Paint`
- Provide a Checked property on the derived `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`, and also a CheckedChanged event
- Substitute the derived `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` in the column's `HeaderCell` when the `DataGridView` is being populated.
- Check and uncheck the `CheckBox` when it is the column header is clicked, only if the mouse click is within the bounds of the `CheckBox`
- Implement the check-all/uncheck-all outside of the derived class by listening to the `CheckedChanged` event, updating the underlying data object and then calling `ResetBindings` to update the `DataGridView`

Here's the class I wrote which is derived from `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell`:

```
class DataGridViewCheckBoxColumnHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
{
    private Bitmap buffer;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private Rectangle checkBoxBounds;

    public DataGridViewCheckBoxColumnHeaderCell()
    {
        this.checkBox = new CheckBox();
    }

    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;

    public bool Checked
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.checkBox.Checked; 
        }

        set
        {
            if (!this.Checked == value)
            {
                this.checkBox.Checked = value;
                if (this.buffer != null)
                {
                    this.buffer.Dispose();
                    this.buffer = null;
                }

                this.OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs.Empty);

                if (this.DataGridView != null)
                {
                    this.DataGridView.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Paint(
        Graphics graphics, 
        Rectangle clipBounds, 
        Rectangle cellBounds, 
        int rowIndex, 
        DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState, 
        object value, 
        object formattedValue, 
        string errorText, 
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, 
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        // Passing String.Empty in place of 
        // value and formattedValue prevents 
        // this header cell from having text.

        base.Paint(
            graphics, 
            clipBounds, 
            cellBounds, 
            rowIndex, 
            dataGridViewElementState, 
            String.Empty, 
            String.Empty, 
            errorText, 
            cellStyle, 
            advancedBorderStyle, 
            paintParts);

        if (this.buffer == null 
            || cellBounds.Width != this.buffer.Width
            || cellBounds.Height != this.buffer.Height)
        {
            this.UpdateBuffer(cellBounds.Size);
        }

        graphics.DrawImage(this.buffer, cellBounds.Location);
    }

    protected override Size GetPreferredSize(
        Graphics graphics, 
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
        int rowIndex, 
        Size constraintSize)
    {
        return this.checkBox.GetPreferredSize(constraintSize);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left 
            && this.checkBoxBounds.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            this.Checked = !this.Checked;
        }

        base.OnMouseClick(e);
    }

    private void UpdateBuffer(Size size)
    {
        Bitmap updatedBuffer = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);

        this.checkBox.Size = size;

        if (this.checkBox.Size.Width > 0 && this.checkBox.Size.Height > 0)
        {
            Bitmap renderedCheckbox = new Bitmap(
                this.checkBox.Width, 
                this.checkBox.Height);

            this.checkBox.DrawToBitmap(
                renderedCheckbox, 
                new Rectangle(new Point(), this.checkBox.Size));

            MakeTransparent(renderedCheckbox, this.checkBox.BackColor);
            Bitmap croppedRenderedCheckbox = AutoCrop(
                renderedCheckbox, 
                Color.Transparent);

            // TODO implement alignment, right now it is always
            // MiddleCenter regardless of this.Style.Alignment

            this.checkBox.Location = new Point(
                (updatedBuffer.Width - croppedRenderedCheckbox.Width) / 2, 
                (updatedBuffer.Height - croppedRenderedCheckbox.Height) / 2);

            Graphics updatedBufferGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(updatedBuffer);
            updatedBufferGraphics.DrawImage(
                croppedRenderedCheckbox, 
                this.checkBox.Location);

            this.checkBoxBounds = new Rectangle(
                this.checkBox.Location, 
                croppedRenderedCheckbox.Size);

            renderedCheckbox.Dispose();
            croppedRenderedCheckbox.Dispose();
        }

        if (this.buffer != null)
        {
            this.buffer.Dispose();
        }

        this.buffer = updatedBuffer;
    }

    protected virtual void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = this.CheckedChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    // The methods below are helper methods for manipulating Bitmaps

    private static void MakeTransparent(Bitmap bitmap, Color transparencyMask)
    {
        int transparencyMaskArgb = transparencyMask.ToArgb();
        int transparentArgb = Color.Transparent.ToArgb();

        List deadColumns = new List();

        for (int x = 0; x = 0; x--)
        {
            if (deadColumns.Count == bitmap.Height)
            {
                break;
            }

            for (int y = bitmap.Height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                if (deadColumns.Contains(y))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                int pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb();

                if (pixel == transparencyMaskArgb)
                {
                    bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
                }
                else if (pixel != transparentArgb)
                {
                    deadColumns.Add(y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap AutoCrop(Bitmap bitmap, Color backgroundColor)
    {
        Size croppedSize = bitmap.Size;
        Point cropOrigin = new Point();
        int backgroundColorToArgb = backgroundColor.ToArgb();

        for (int x = bitmap.Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            bool allPixelsAreBackgroundColor = true;
            for (int y = bitmap.Height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                if (bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb() != backgroundColorToArgb)
                {
                    allPixelsAreBackgroundColor = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (allPixelsAreBackgroundColor)
            {
                croppedSize.Width--;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int y = bitmap.Height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            bool allPixelsAreBackgroundColor = true;
            for (int x = bitmap.Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                if (bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb() != backgroundColorToArgb)
                {
                    allPixelsAreBackgroundColor = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (allPixelsAreBackgroundColor)
            {
                croppedSize.Height--;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x = 0 && xWhole = 0)
                {
                    bitmapSection.SetPixel(x, y, bitmap.GetPixel(xWhole, yWhole));
                }
                else
                {
                    bitmapSection.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
                }
            }
        }

        return bitmapSection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is bit old but could You please provide full example of this? When I try to use Your code I get errors.

Comment: last part of the code is full of error FOR followed by a ELSE. can you please correct it

Comment: hi tanx for ur reply , how to use this class ?? plz describ for me

Answer (score 13):

The above solution is kind of good, but there is also an easier way!
Simply add these two methods and then you would have what you want!

First add a `show_chkBox` method to your code and call it in the `onload` function of your form or after creating your `DataGridView`:

```
 private void show_chkBox()
 {
     Rectangle rect = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);
     // set checkbox header to center of header cell. +1 pixel to position 
     rect.Y = 3;
     rect.X = rect.Location.X + (rect.Width/4);
     CheckBox checkboxHeader = new CheckBox();
     checkboxHeader.Name = "checkboxHeader";
     //datagridview[0, 0].ToolTipText = "sdfsdf";
     checkboxHeader.Size = new Size(18, 18);
     checkboxHeader.Location = rect.Location;
     checkboxHeader.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged);
     dataGridView1.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader);
 }
```

and then you would have the checkbox in the header.

For the selecting problem, just add this code:

```
private void checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{             
    CheckBox headerBox = ((CheckBox)dataGridView1.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader", true)[0]);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = headerBox.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good, but check one checkbox independently and the whole thing gets out of sync.

Comment: I don't think so, I have been using this code for a long time, and haven't seen this problem. Can you tell me exactly what you're doing?

Comment: I tried many examples but my checkbox is always on the top left corner of the grid view. Any reasons for that?

Comment: found the problem: I was running the code before showing the form

Comment: put the this.dataGridView1.EndEdit(); after ending of for loop

Comment: if not selecting first row see the comments from @NituBansal and Solution Below from   Ana.. Just Specifying why those lines to be added .. I was struggling for quite long.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you choose @Ehsan solution you must know that if the checkbox cell is selected it won't update the checkbox UI. You need to call RefreshEdit() afterwards.

It only happens when the control is child-control of the datagridview. For some reason when it is a child-control the selected cell checkboxes are not able to refresh the UI by their own.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's an important piece to include.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ehsan for the easy way, works fine for me. For the problem only one CheckBox is always at the upper left corner, I add a name suffix to each one and solved. In addition, I would like to slightly modify the event handling method by directly cast the object sender since it was very specific up on the creation (unless this method is used to handling other kind of controls' event either).

```
private string[] _colLst = columNameArray;
private void AddCheckBoxGridViewHeader()
{
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < _colLst.Length; ndx++)
    {
        var rect = dtgv1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(ndx, -1, true);
        var x = rect.X + (rect.Width * 4 / 5);
        var y = 3;
        Rectangle nrect = new Rectangle(x, y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
        CheckBox checkboxHeader = new CheckBox();
        checkboxHeader.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        checkboxHeader.Name = "checkboxHeader" + ndx;
        checkboxHeader.Size = new Size(18, 18);
        checkboxHeader.Location = nrect.Location;
        checkboxHeader.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged);
        dtgv1.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader);
    }
}

private void checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CheckBox headerBox = ((CheckBox)dtgv1.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader", true)[0]);

    var headerBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    var b = headerBox.Checked;
    var c = int.Parse(headerBox.Name.Replace("checkboxHeader", ""));
    for (int i = 0; i < dtgv1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        dtgv1.Rows[i].Cells[c].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle(); 
        dtgv1.Rows[i].Cells[c].Style.BackColor = (b)? Color.Salmon : Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

So - to address the top-most checkbox not showing as checked (even though it is), I ended up editing your event as follows:

```
private void checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  //CheckBox headerBox = ((CheckBox)dtgv1.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader", true)[0]);

  var headerBox = (CheckBox) sender;
  var b = headerBox.Checked;
  var c = int.Parse(headerBox.Name.Replace("checkboxHeader", ""));
  for (int i = 0; i < dgvSources_fuzzyID.RowCount; i++) {
    dgvSources_fuzzyID.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = headerBox.Checked; **
    * dgvSources_fuzzyID.RefreshEdit(); ** *
  }
}
```

That is what finally fixed it for me...

Answer (score 0):

Following is the solution that worked for me as Ehsaan's solution was not checking the first row in the `DataGridView`.

Call the `AddChkBoxHeader_DataGridView()` method in `OnLoad` function of your form.

```
CheckBox checkboxHeader = null;
bool isHeaderCheckBoxClicked = false;
private void AddChkBoxHeader_DataGridView()
{
    Rectangle rect = dgvRecipeSelector.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);
    rect.Y = 10;
    rect.X = rect.Location.X + (rect.Width / 4);            
    checkboxHeader = new CheckBox();
    checkboxHeader.Size = new Size(15,15);
    checkboxHeader.Location = rect.Location;
    dgvRecipeSelector.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader);
    checkboxHeader.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged);
}

private void checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    HeaderCheckBoxClick((CheckBox)sender);
}

private void HeaderCheckBoxClick(CheckBox headerCheckbox)
{
    isHeaderCheckBoxClicked = true;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvRecipeSelector.Rows)
    {
        ((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)r.Cells[0]).Value = headerCheckbox.Checked;
    }
    dgvRecipeSelector.RefreshEdit();
    isHeaderCheckBoxClicked = false;
}
```