# how to change the color in datagridview row when i check the checkbox in C# windows applications?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, windows

how to change the color in datagridview row when i check the check box in C# windows applications?i have code for select one check box is in header column in datagridview it checks all check boxes and changing background color in a datagridview rows but i want when check one check box and corresponding datagridview row will change color please help me

```
 private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ckBox.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ckBox_CheckedChanged);
        this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(ckBox);   
    }

    void ckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
        {
            this.dataGridView1[2, j].Value = this.ckBox.Checked;
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell check = row.Cells["Chk"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(check.Value) == true)
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
            else
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
```

Comment: This link might help you [How to have Checkbox as ColumnHeader of dataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868654/how-to-have-checkbox-as-columnheader-of-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

The code to add the `CheckBox` to the header works pretty well already.

To align the `CheckBox` to the right you need to calculate the position maybe like this:

```
    ckBox.Location = new Point(rect.Right - ckBox.Width - 4, rect.Top + 4);
```

I have added a few pixels padding. You will want to make the column wide enough to prevent the `CheckBox` overlapping the header text.

But you will need to **repeat the alignment** whenever the user changes a column's width or the column order or when new columns get added.

So I suggest to move the alignment code into a function you can call when needed:

```
void layoutCheckBox()
{
    Rectangle rect = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(2, -1, true);
    ckBox.Location = new Point(rect.Right - ckBox.Width - 4, rect.Top + 4);
}
```

For example here:

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    layoutCheckBox();
}
```

And then some, as mentioned; depending on what the user can do..

As for the `CheckChanged` code it seems to work, provided the cells in column `Chk` indeed all are `DataGridViewCheckBoxCells`..