# how to create a CheckBox on dataGridView Header Column C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

how to create a checkBox header in dataGridView , I have a dataGridView and i have a CheckBox Column index=12
and i need to do a checkBox on the header , this is my code but i have a error how can i do change this code to fix it , to create the checkBox header. any body can help???? i add some code to explain what i need to do.

```cs
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
 //i have error here
dataGridViewSellers.Columns[12].HeaderCell = checkBoxCell;

foreach(Seller aSeller in sellers){
    DataGridViewButtonCell buttonEditCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
    DataGridViewButtonCell buttonDeleteCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
    DataGridViewButtonCell buttonRestPassCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
    dataGridViewSellers[0, i].Value = aSeller.IdNumber;
    dataGridViewSellers[1, i].Value = aSeller.Name;
    dataGridViewSellers[2, i].Value = aSeller.LastName;
    dataGridViewSellers[3, i].Value = aSeller.PhoneNumber;
    dataGridViewSellers[4, i].Value = aSeller.Address;
    dataGridViewSellers[5, i].Value = aSeller.Email;
    dataGridViewSellers[6, i].Value = aSeller.UserName;
    dataGridViewSellers[7, i].Value = aSeller.EntryDate;
    dataGridViewSellers[8, i].Value = aSeller.BusinessHours;
    dataGridViewSellers[9, i] = buttonEditCell;
    dataGridViewSellers[10, i] = buttonDeleteCell;
    dataGridViewSellers[11, i] = buttonRestPassCell;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have Checkbox as ColumnHeader of dataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868654/how-to-have-checkbox-as-columnheader-of-datagridview)

Comment: In future, if you have an issue involving an error message or exception, please post the error message as well so that we can help you out without needing to compile your code

Comment: See the notes and sample code here: [How to replace the HeaderCells of a DataGridView with custom headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63011702/7444103). That code adds a Button to the Cell Header, but of course you can add any other control you like.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fixed code..

```
    private void AddHeaderCheckBox()
    {
        HeaderCheckBox = new CheckBox();

        HeaderCheckBox.Size = new Size(15, 15);

        //Add the CheckBox into the DataGridView
        this.dataGridViewSellers.Controls.Add(HeaderCheckBox);
    }

    private void ResetLocation(int ColumnIndex, int RowIndex)
    {
        //Get the column header cell bounds
        Rectangle oRectangle =
          this.dataGridViewSellers.GetCellDisplayRectangle(ColumnIndex, RowIndex, true);

        Point oPoint = new Point();


        oPoint.X = oRectangle.Location.X + (oRectangle.Width - HeaderCheckBox.Width) / 2 + 1;
        oPoint.Y = oRectangle.Location.Y + (oRectangle.Height - HeaderCheckBox.Height) / 2 + 1;

        //Change the location of the CheckBox to make it stay on the header
        HeaderCheckBox.Location = oPoint;
    }
```